# Where are my git credential stored in vscode remote development?

Tags: git, vscode-remote

So I started to use `vscode` remote development capabilities via `ssh`.
On an initial `git pull` on the vscode terminal, it (out of the box) did the OAuth and 2FA dance (opening a browser locally) to log me into github.

So far so automagically good.

However, I am not alone on the remote machine. A do not want that my github credentials can be accessed by another user.

When I issue a `printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com" | git credential fill` in the remote vscode terminal, my credentials are dumped.

**Where do these come from?**
And if located on the remote host, how can I erase my credentials?

When I run the above `git credential fill`command on a remote non-vscode shell, then nothing is dumped.

Also there is no credential helper configured on the remote machine.

On the local machine, the `credential manager` is configured, so

```
 printf "host=github.com\nusername=***\nprotocol=https" | git credential-manager get
```

will dump my credentials. So maybe vscode takes the credentials from this?

However, if I erase the credential locally with `git credential-manager erase` (and even after restarting vscode), the credentials still show in the vscode remote terminal.

See also [Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)

Comment: I hope someone can answer, I have been wondering the same thing. My conclusion, though, was that my credentials were somehow on my local machine, and the Git connections were happening via my local machine, because in a regular terminal to the same server, Git is unable to connect to GitHub, while in the VSCode terminal window, Git can. It's all still a bit mysterious to me how this works...

Answer (score 0):

On MS-Windows, `vscode` stores the credential locally in Windows Credential Manager (Anmeldeinformationen) under `vscodevscode.github-authentication/github.auth`.

After deleting this entry **and** restart of `vscode` remote session a `printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com" | git credential fill` does not dump the existing credentials anymore, but wants to sign in again. So that verifies it.

Btw, the secret stored under `vscodevscode.github-authentication/github.auth` is not the github personal access token, but an oauth token.